# connect a UINavigation Controller to table view within view based app

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an view based app that has a main menu. In the main menu the user can select an option that presents a table that is populated from an SQLite database (BrowseView). That is all working fine, however from the table I want the user to be able to select a row of data that will present a detailed view and I cannot get the detailed view to work. Nothing happens.

I think the problem is that I havn't connected the detailed view to the UINavigation controller but I'm unsure on how to do this as I have tried everything that I can think of (which is probably not much as I'm new to programming).

Any help on this would be greatly appreicated. Here is my code.

In the appDelegate.h

```
@class ClubFindViewController;

@interface ClubFindAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
ClubFindViewController *viewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController;

NSMutableArray *clubArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ClubFindViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *clubArray;

-(void) copyDatadaseIfNeeded;
-(NSString *) getDBPath;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation ClubFindAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize navigationController;
@synthesize clubArray;



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

[self copyDatadaseIfNeeded];
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.clubArray = tempArray;
[tempArray release];

[Clubs getInitialDataToDisplay:[self getDBPath]];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

DetailView.h

```
@class Clubs;


@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController {
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
Clubs *clubObj;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Clubs *clubObj;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


@end
```

DetailView.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Clubs.h"
#import "BrowseViewController.h"


@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize clubObj;
@synthesize tableView;


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.title = clubObj.clubName;
[self.tableView reloadData];

}



-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section {
NSString *sectionName = nil;
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        sectionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Club"];
        break;
    case 1:
        sectionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Address"];
        break;
}
return sectionName;

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 1;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = clubObj.clubName;
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = clubObj.ClubAddress;
        break;
}

return cell;


}
```

Updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your app and want to use UINavigationController you must in your AppDelegate tell that UINavigationController is your rootViewController.

`self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;`

When the Detail view will be pushed it will already (know) that it is inside the UINavigationController and so you don't need to create additional UINavigationController.

So delete `UINavigationController *navigationController;` from both .h and .m file.

Comment: Thanks Cyprian for your responce however that has not worked can you recommend something else.@Cyrpian

Comment: Sometimes little things may go wrong along the way, but the approach I gave you should work. Pls update your code. Let me see the AppDelegate class as well as your .h and .m Detail file. One more thing did you insert the UINavigationViewController in the MainWindow.xib? I recommend you to create a new project from template "Navigation-based application" it will setup an UINavigationViewController for you.

Comment: I have updated my code as requested. No I have not inserted the UINaviagationViewController in the MainWindow.xib (how do I do this). I orginaly wrote the program using a "Navigation based templete" however I had the same problem when I added the main menu view (the DetailView work prior to add this view) and was advised to change it to a view based app.@Cyprian